# Can't delete my comment on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Why can't I delete my comment on my own post? I answered a question and the concerned commented a query, on my answer. I was writing a comment in return and by mistake, I pressed Enter and comment got posted midway. I cannot delete it and it's awkwardly hung in there. There are no options, not even edit near the comment. At the end I had to edit my original answer instead of making comments.  [Click here to see a screen recording](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwgnFJDMh7GsYXkwZTBmRlBZTDQ)
[image: Here's a screenshot.]

Comment: Were you login when you tried? It's an light grey times (x) at the end of the comment right side of edit link. Anyway i think this question is for meta

Comment: Yea I was, and the delete option comes on my comments on other posts, but not in this specific post. And by meta you mean, I should post there?

Comment: @StephenLeppik following is the link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129568/return-a-string-in-java/41131001?noredirect=1#comment69473311_41131001

Comment: You are aware that you need to *hover your mouse over the comment* for the options to pop up…?

Comment: @deceze Yes sir. I added a link to view screen recording to help the case further :)

Comment: Can you inspect the HTML to see if it has a `<a class="comment-delete` node?

Comment: @Stijn On checking the source code I didn't find any class="comment-delete" node.

Comment: Could be a permission bug then, perhaps an incorrect reputation requirement for deleting comments.

Comment: @Stijn they don't have the Comment Everywhere privilege, so they can't delete the comments that they've posted? Doesn't make much sense tbh

Comment: @StephenLeppik That's why I said it *could* be a bug. It wouldn't be the first bug regarding that specific privilege, IIRC. We'll have to wait for a dev to look at it now.

Comment: Could be that you were logged out at the time?

Comment: @Oded OP was logged in in the recording, since they had the option to delete their answer.

Comment: Then I'd suspect some JavaScript/CSS not loading correctly. Did you check the dev tools console?

Comment: @Oded Yes I did, it didn't show any errors. Is there any specific files I should check for? Something which might not show error if missing?

Comment: @AnuritaSrivastava - if nothing shows up on the console? Not really. The network tab would tell you if something didn't load, but then I'd also expect errors on the console.

Comment: Other things to check: any user scripts running? Ad blockers? Other extensions/plug-ins/add-ons?

Comment: Also - is this still on going? Or did it just happen the one time (or period of time)? Was it a specific question or the whole site?

Comment: @Oded I didn't see any errors on console. And it's still going on but on a particular question only. As I mentioned before also, the delete option comes on my comments on other posts, but not in this specific post. And there's no ad blockers. The only extensions are Google Docs and Color Picker.

Comment: Can you link to the post? Did you try clearing your cache and reloading the page?

Comment: Following is the link to the post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129568/return-a-string-in-java/41131001#41131001
 @Oded I tried by clearing the cache also.

Comment: So, logged in, cleared the cache, reloaded the page, no extensions, no network or script errors and only happens on that particular page?

Comment: Well, found the bug. Rather subtle. Something changed a couple of months ago.

Comment: @Oded Yes on that page only. And oh, what is the issue then?

Comment: The ownership of post check was messed up - I expect that on questions and answers on your questions it was right, but specifically for answers on someone else posts it was returning the wrong thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an issue with the test for users who do not have the comment everywhere privilege - specifically for those who were answering someone else question. The check gave an incorrect result when checking for post ownership.

I have updated the check to give the correct result - this is being deployed now.

Comment: I'm able to delete that comment now :)